# NVidia 840m problem with Ubuntu 14.04 ("screan tearing")

Tags: 14.04, asus, nvidia-settings

I have a problem with an Asus TP500LN with an NVidia 840m. I have installed the nvidia-340 driver, but I have "screen tearing" problems. In `nvidia-settings`, in the OpenGL section there isn't a vsync item...

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Next time, please use your [Shift] key for correct CaPiTaLiSaTiOn!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do.

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some more guidance after reading their page, leave a comment below.